# Executing multiple queries with rust driver in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I’m using Rust driver to connect to Memgraph instance and execute multiple `MATCH` / `CREATE` queries.

Is there any way I can execute multiple queries with method:

`connection.execute_without_results` ?

In other words - I dont want a sequence of queries like:

`connection.execute_without_results(query1) connection.execute_without_results(query2) connection.execute_without_results(query3)`

But I want them like this:
`connection.execute_without_results(query1;query2;query3)`

I have also noticed it works for MERGE queries like:

`MERGE (:Node) MERGE (:Node1) MERGE (:Node2) MERGE (:Node3)`

But I also need other MATCH queries ( like create relations ).

Answer (score 0):

The `execute_without_results`method in the Rust driver for Memgraph executes a single query without returning any results. To execute multiple queries in a single call, you can concatenate them into a single string and pass it as a parameter to `execute_without_results`

```
use memgraph::Connection;

pub async fn execute_multiple_queries(connection: &mut Connection, queries: &[&str]) {
    let combined_query = queries.join("; ");
    connection.execute_without_results(&combined_query).await.unwrap();
}
```

The `execute_multiple_queries` function takes a mutable reference to a Connection and a slice of query strings (queries). It joins all the queries using a semicolon as the separator and then passes the combined query to execute_without_results.

You can call the `execute_multiple_queries` function with your list of queries like this:

```
let mut connection = Connection::connect("memgraph://localhost").await.unwrap();

let queries = [
    "MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n",
    "MATCH (n:Node1) RETURN n",
    "MATCH (n:Node2) RETURN n",
    "MATCH (n:Node3) RETURN n",
];

execute_multiple_queries(&mut connection, &queries).await;
```

This will execute all the queries in the queries array as a single batch using the `execute_without_results` method. Note that the queries should be separated by a semicolon (;) in the combined query string.